# Converting Antd Form.Item to reagent-hiccup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, clojurescript, hiccup

I'm trying to translate a `antd` react form item to reagent-hiccup.

The original react component is something like this,

```
        <Form.Item>
          {
            <Input
              prefix={<Icon type="user"/>}
              placeholder="Username"
            />
          }
        </Form.Item>
```

And I tried the below variations when I tried to convert it into reagent hiccup representation.

**Variation 1:**

```
[:> Form.Item
   [:> Input
    {:prefix [:> Icon {:type "user"}] :placeholder "Username"}]]
```

**Variation 2:**

```
[:> Form.Item
   [:> Input
    {:prefix [:> js/antd.Icon {:type "user"}] :placeholder "Username"}]]
```

**Variation 3:**

```
(defn antd-username []
  [:> Form.Item
   [:> Input
    {:prefix (r/as-component [:span [:> Icon {:type "user"}]]) :placeholder "Username"}]])
```

None of them worked and I'm getting the below error,

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in span
    in span
    in Unknown (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by ForwardRef)
    in ForwardRef (created by app.auth.views.login.antd_username)
    in div
    in div
    in div (created by Col)
    in Col
    in Unknown
    in div (created by Row)
    in Row
.
.
.
.
```

Whereas if I remove the prefix part it works. So I don't have any other issues.

What's the right way of converting the aforementioned component to reagent-hiccup?

Answer (score 0):

There are React components, instances, and elements. You almost got it in your third variation - you do need to wrap Hiccup vectors with something for React components to understand them. `<Icon .../>` creates a React element, so so seems like `prefix=...` expects an element. All you gotta do is replace `r/as-component` in your third variation with `r/as-element`.

Comment: No luck still,

Getting the below err,
```
react.development.js:316 Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```
For,

```
[:> Form.Item
   [:> Input
    {:prefix (r/as-element [:span [:> Icon {:type "user"}]]) :placeholder "Username"}]]
```

Comment: Add `(js/console.log Icon)` somewhere at the top level. Does it log some component or `undefined`? If the former - no idea, I'd need a repo with a minimal reproducible example to check it myself. If the latter - your `:require` for `Icon` is incorrect.

Comment: Was caught up with other things before coming back here. That was really helpful. I was importing `Icon` from `antd` like `[antd :refer [Icon]]`.

Then I had to do a package.json install of `"@ant-design/icons"` and import required icon from there.

Can you add the version of import suggestion as an answer so that I can mark it as answer to help others? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "the version of import suggestion", but feel free to edit my answer - your reputation should allow it.